# How can i access the objects variable inside an objects function (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, windows-8, javascript-objects

```
(function () {
    var id="test";
    $.ajax({
       context: this,
       url : "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss",
       success : function(data){
            this.id = "was test";
       }
    });
    console.log(id);
})();
```

The previous question wasn't clear enough so hear is what the question really is. When I'm doing `console.log(id)` it doesn't show the changed value. What I'd like to get is the changed value of `id`. How can I achieve this, I've tried all the solutions in the comments and the given answers as well but none has worked for me?

A jsFiddle will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: you have syntax error, use your console

Comment: @roasted I can't see that, where is that?

Comment: @KamranAhmed closing success callback using `});` instead of `}`

Comment: @roasted that was a typing mistake. I'm trying something different

Comment: you are trying something different than your posted code?! So why not posting the 'something different' code?...

Comment: @roasted I think that's not a big deal, **he is trying to access the object property inside the for each loop of another object** so I think the code posted is enough to make us understand what he is asking.

Comment: @KamranAhmed ya and this has been already answered

Answer (score 1):

In *getTodayCats*:

```
var self = this;
```

And then when need to access **ids**, you should get it like this:

```
self.ids
```

The usage of the *self, this* pattern is made in this case since you need to access a property of *this* in an asynchronous callback handler(ajax success). Handlers for asynchronous callbacks are called without the original *this* object, so this is used to utilize the function's closure to pass in the original.

In case of the jQuery's *ajax* method, you could also use the *context* option to pass in the *this* object which will be used for its callback handlers. It's up to you on whether you use it. I personally prefer not to, since this isn't an option for other async handlers such as in the case of timeout and intervals, and I prefer to keep it consistent.

Comment: $.ajax get an option for that, the `context` option

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost/woodenspoon/getTodaysCats.php",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     responseType: "json",
     context: this,
     success: function (data) {

         this.ids = "ok";

     }
 });
```

Comment: what'd you say about the updated code, I've tried your way but it didn't work for me!!

Answer (score 0):

Access "ids" this way-

```
getTodaysCats: function () {

    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( WinJS.UI.Pages.define.arguments);
    var ids = args[1].ids;
    $.ajax({               
        ...
        , success: function (data) {
            var arr = new Array(1,2,3,4,5);
            foreach(var num in arr)
                ids += "ok";    
        }
    });

    return ids;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try using something like this...

`${variable}`